# Gradle sync failed for the latest version of Gradle 2.14.1

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Since I've upgraded my Gradle to the latest version right now which is 2.14.1 it keeps failing to sync ,I have tried the solutions provided for the same exact problem in older versions of Gradle but it keeps failing again, it says 
Gradle sync failed : No catched version of com.android.tools.build : Gradle:2.14.1 available for offline mode

Comment: `Gradle:2.14.1 available for offline mode` remove offline mode or click  logcat `offline mode` . then gradle please (with internet)

Answer (score 0):

Setting -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Graddle then disable Offline work

Comment: I read it for previous versions it said that I needed to disable the offline and restart android studio and enable it again but I did it also what you said didn't work